# populate ArrayList with user input

Tags: java, arraylist

I am sure this has been asked 1000 times, but I cannot fig this out for the life of me. I have searched stack overflow, google, code ranch etc. and cannot find what I am looking for. I need to be able to take a number and add it to an ArrayList when it is generated. The program generates a random number and then ask the user to try and guess what it is. I can get the number of guesses to populate correctly, but I cannot get it to store in the ArrayList. I need each guess to be in a new index, and I do not know how many I will need due to how many games the user decided to play. I am not even sure if the ArrayList is what I need to use. The point of storing them is so I can find the greatest number of guesses for later in the program. Here is my code for guessing the number and displaying it to the user. I am using guesses as the int to store the info from the users guess. I am new to JAVA, so please excuse all the comments to keep me on track.

```
    public static void guessNumber() {

    //Totals the games played by the user
    gamesPlayed++;
    //Scanner to allow user input
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Prints "Your guess ? " for the user to input their guess
    System.out.print("Your guess ? ");
    // Input for the number the user guessed
    int numberGuessed = console.nextInt();

    //While loop with nested if statement to check if the number guessed by the user is equal to the random number generated, if not,
    //show higher or lower hints depending on the guess
    while (numberGuessed != randomNumber) {

        //if statement to determine if the guess is higher or lower than the random number
        //if the guess is higher, show the random number is lower than the guess, than ask the user to guess again
        if (numberGuessed > randomNumber) {
            //Prints "lower" for the user to know the number is lower than the guess, 
            //Prints "Your guess ? " for the user to guess again
            System.out.println("lower");
            System.out.print("Your guess ? ");
            //End of if statement and begins else if statement to determine if the guess is higher or lower than the random number
            //If the guess is lower, show the random number is higher than the guess, 
            //Prints "Your guess ? " for the user to guess again
        } else if (numberGuessed < randomNumber) {
            //Prints "higher" for the user to know the number is higher than the guess, 
            //"Your guess ? " for the user to guess again
            System.out.println("higher");
            System.out.print("Your guess ? ");
        }// End of else if statement

        // Input for the number the user guessed
        numberGuessed = console.nextInt();
        //Counts the number of tries it took to guess the correct number
        guesses++;
        //Totals all the guesses made in the games played
        totalGuesses++;

    }//End of while loop

    //Array for storing guesses
    System.out.println("");      
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; guesses > i; i++) {
        test.add(guesses);
    System.out.println("Elements of ArrayList of Integer Type: "+ test);
    }

    //Shows the user guessed the right number and how many tries it took to guess the number
    System.out.println("You got it right in " + guesses + " guesses" + "\n");
    //Ask the user if they want to play again
    System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");
    //Input for the user to input yes or no if they want to play again or not
    String playAgain = console.next();
    //Prints blank line
    System.out.println("");
    //Totals all the guesses made in the game
    double endingTotalGuesses = totalGuesses + gamesPlayed;

    //If statement to check and see if the user wants to play again and ignores the case of the word no
    if (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        //Resets the number of guesses when a used starts a new game
        guesses = 1;
        //Prints I'm thinking of a number...
        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number...");
        //Calls the generateRandomNumber method to pick a random number to guess
        generateRandomNumber();
        //Assigns the generateRandomNumber method to the integer randomNumber
        randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
        //*Remove this line that shows what the number is!*
        System.out.println("The number is: " + randomNumber);
        //Calls the guessNumber method to allow the game to start over and the user to start guessing
        guessNumber();
        //End of if statement and starts the else if statement to see if the user wants to play again and ignores the case of the word no
    } else if (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        //else if statement. If the user chooses no, it will call the endOfGames method and pass the 
        //ending amount of guesses and total of games played
        endOfGames(endingTotalGuesses, gamesPlayed);

    }//end of else if statement

}//End of guessNumber method
```

Comment: What do you mean "I cannot get it to store in the ArrayList"?  Does it not compile?  Does it compile and then not print the list correctly when you do `System.out.println("Elements of ArrayList of Integer Type: "+ test);`?

Comment: It compiles and runs, I am having problems getting more than one entry to write to the Array. I have tired int.Next() to try and get it to move to the next spot, and I have do while and not had any success with that either. I honestly do not know if I need the loop or not. I need it to write the number to the array, then when the user guesses again, it writes the next value in to the same array. The best way I can explain it is, the first guess will be saved in the 0 location, the second guess in 1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The only place it appears you're using a `List` is here:

```
System.out.println("");      
ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; guesses > i; i++) {
    test.add(guesses);
    System.out.println("Elements of ArrayList of Integer Type: "+ test);
}
```

In each iteration through the loop, you are adding the exact same values, which is the integer referenced by `guesses`. E.g., if it took 5 guesses, you'd be adding the number *5* to the array 5 times.

You'll dereference `test` every time you exit `guessNumber()`, so in order to keep it in scope, you either need to do something useful with it there, or have a class-level ("field") variable reference the `ArrayList`.

Also, I noticed that you're calling `generateRandomNumber()` needlessly twice:

```
//Calls the generateRandomNumber method to pick a random number to guess
generateRandomNumber();
//Assigns the generateRandomNumber method to the integer randomNumber
randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
```

The first time is wasted -- its returned value is unused.

Comment: Thank you, noted on the calling the method twice and the unused return.

Comment: I have tried a few things, the one I have gotten to work, sort of.                                List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
        int listSize = 1; 
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) {
        
            test.add(guesses);
        
    }    It will write to the list, but only does it once and changes every time I enter another guess. It is overwriting every time due to the list length only being one from what I can tell. I need it to move to the next index and store the variable whenever a new number of guesses is entered'